# Parse: count of objects with pointer to another type object with given ID

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have defined a Parse core object of type X that has a pointer to another object of type Y as one of its attributes. There are about 1000 of type X objects defined and about 20 of type Y objects.

I need to create a JavaScript query that would start with object ID for a type Y object and get count of type X objects that contain pointer to a type Y object with this object ID.

This would be a very easy query against a traditional SQL-based back-end, but in Parse I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using a relational query. Lets assume you have a local instance of an object of class Y, then the query would look like this

```
var ObjectX = Parse.Object.extend("X");
var query = new Parse.Query(ObjectX);
query.equalTo("objectYField", myObjectOfTypeY);
query.count({
  success: function(count) {
    // The count request succeeded. Show the count
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // The request failed
  }
});
```

One small caveat from the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-counting-objects) though

> Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per
>   minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more
>   than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your
>   application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters,
>   for example.)

Comment: This query starts with the myObjectOfTypeY. In my case, I start with the objectId of myObjectOfTypeY, not the whole object.

Comment: If you just have the ID, you should be able to create an empty object of that type, set the ID and pass it in for objectYField (see https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.createWithoutData)